# Using json.loads in Python 2.7 returns unicode object instead of dict

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary, unicode

I'm running into an issue with parsing JSON data into a dict which I cannot figure out.

I'm connecting to a Tornado websocket from JavaScript and sending the following data, entered into a textfield:

```
{"action": "something"}
```

The way I'm sending it to the websocket is:

```
sock.send( JSON.stringify( $('textfield').value ) );
```

Now in Python I have the following code in my WebsocketHandler::on_message():

```
print("Message type: " + str(type(message)) + ", content: " + message)

parsed_message = json.loads(message)

print("Parsed message type: " + str(type(parsed_message)) + ", content: " + parsed_message)
```

And the output from this is:

```
Message type: <type 'unicode'>, content: "{\"action\":\"START_QUESTION_SELF\"}"
Parsed message type: <type 'unicode'>, content: {"action":"START_QUESTION_SELF"}
```

Now I would expect the second printed message to be a `dict` and I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if i've misunderstood but content: {"action":"START_QUESTION_SELF"} is actually a dict.

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: @M.T, I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @SerhanOztekin It's being received as a unicode string, and after a call to `json.loads()` it's still seen as a unicode object and I cannot use it as a dict.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this using python 2.7. I get `Parsed message type: <type 'dict'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you do `sock.send(JSON.stringify('{"action": "something"}'));` you send this `"{\"action\": \"something\"}"`

When you print message you can verify that it actually contains quotes. Hence, it is being interpreted as a string by `json.loads`.

Easiest solution would be invoking `json.loads` again:

```
parsed_message = json.loads(json.loads(message))
```

However you should really consider converting textfield value into an object and then using `JSON.stringify` on it. Something like this:

```
sock.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse( $('textfield').value)));
```

Comment: I changed the sending of of the data to:

    `sock.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse($('textfield').value)));`

And now get a dict on the Python end. Thanks!

Comment: @Revell Huh. I've just proposed the very same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I seems like your string is escaped  (`\"`), and thus `json.loads` sees it as a plain string.
Try to unescape `message` before calling `json.loads`.

I've had the same error when using JSONField in models and setting the json to this

```
content='{"content":"Hello A","numbers":[1,2,3,4]}'
# json.loads(model.content) --> type 'str'
```

Instead of

```
content={"content":"Hello A","numbers":[1,2,3,4]}
# json.loads(model.content) --> type 'dict'
```